# ElasticSearch and nested query

Tags: elasticsearch

Having a problem getting record with intersecting ('and') condition. 
I have a doc:

```
{
        "uuid": "1e2a0c06-af24-42e1-a31a-0f84233521de",
        "subject": "subj",
        "relations": [
            {
                "userUuid": "0f38e576-6b1f-4c1a-86a8-67a55a06d504",
                "signed": false
            },
            {
                "userUuid": "15979293-6b04-41a9-a6aa-bba99499496f",
                "signed": true
            }
        ]
}
```

Querying and expecting to get EMPTY result, cause conditions are met from different nested elements:

```
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "relations.userUuid": {
                                "value": "15979293-6b04-41a9-a6aa-bba99499496f",
                                "boost": 1.0
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "relations",
                    "ignore_unmapped": false,
                    "score_mode": "none",
                    "boost": 1.0
                }
            },
            {
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "relations.signed": {
                                "value": false,
                                "boost": 1.0
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "relations",
                    "ignore_unmapped": false,
                    "score_mode": "none",
                    "boost": 1.0
                }
            }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1.0
    }
}
```

How to query that condition would be 'AND' within same nested object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the answer looking at your comment. You need to mention `path` in your nested document.

**Scenario 1:** If you want any of the nested documents to contain `5979293-6b04-41a9-a6aa-bba99499496f` as `userUuid` and `signed` as `true`

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "relations",         <---- Note this
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "relations.userUuid": "15979293-6b04-41a9-a6aa-bba99499496f"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "relations",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "relations.signed": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This would return true if there are two nested documents, first nested doc containing the `userUuid` and second nested doc containing `signed` as `false`

Scenario 2: If you want both the fields to be present in a single nested document

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "relations",       <---- Note this
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "relations.userUuid": "15979293-6b04-41a9-a6aa-bba99499496f"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "relations.signed": false
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In this scenario, a single nested document must contain both values.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: No, mapping is:
'
_mappings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "dynamic": false, "properties" : {"relations": {"type": "nested","properties": { "userUuid":  { "type": "keyword"  }, .......'

Comment: anyway, I tried to add '.keyword', this hasn't helped. I mean now it don't find even matched conditions.

Comment: Could you please check the answer now. I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: What you need is the second query with the value of `relations.signed` as `false` as you want to return only those documents which contain both values in a `single nested document`